# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH when surfing to subdomains of Google

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, firefox, browser

Very strange, I can surf to every website I try. Except **subdomains of google.com**.
ex; firebase.google.com or photos.google.com or analytics.google.com ... 
(I am enable to do normal google searches though)

When I go to these sites Google Chrome returns following error:

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

And it says x.google.com doesn't use a supported protocol.

Same result when using FireFox:

```
SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP
```

Microsoft Edge also raises an error, saying something about the TLS-configuration

As I found it very difficult to believe this is an issue caused by the Google side, I tried two things:

- Cleared my cookies
- Cleared SSL certificates

But no result..   Any idea's?

Comment: I disabled SSL scan in my anti-virus and now it works. But this is a bad fix, no?

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error as the website is still encrypted with the older **RC4 or SHA-1** algorithm.

You must check the status of the **Cipher-suit** of the website, it will help you to understand the correct concern and you can solve the issue.